# Fastest way to swap characters in a string (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I've seen many questions on the most efficient way to do certain things, but one I haven't seen (and one which would help a lot) is the most efficient way to swap two characters in a string. As I thought of it, I immediately went to converting it into a list, swapping the elements, and then joining it back:

```py
def swap(s: str, index1: int, index2: int) -> str:
    new_s = list(s)
    new_s[index1], new_s[index2] = new_s[index2], new_s[index1]
    return "".join(new_s)
```

However, I was wondering if there's a better way. I tried list slicing with something like this:

```py
def swap(s: str, index1: int, index2: int) -> str:
    lindex = min(index1, index2)
    gindex = max(index1, index2)
    return s[:lindex] + s[gindex] + s[lindex + 1:gindex] + s[lindex] + s[gindex + 1:]
```

However, it seemed to be much slower, a whole 45% slower than the first approach. Does anyone of a better (read: more efficient) solution to this? Or is the most efficient way just converting it to a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're wasting time on the function calls to `min` and `max`. You can rewrite your function as:

```
def swap(s: str, index1: int, index2: int) -> str:
    lindex, gindex = (index1, index2) if index1 < index2 else (index2, index1)
    return s[:lindex] + s[gindex] + s[lindex + 1:gindex] + s[lindex] + s[gindex + 1:]
```

and even for small strings it is more performant than the list-based approach.

In fact, as the strings get bigger, the list-based approach gets signficantly slower than using strings directly. For example, with this `timeit` setup

```
from timeit import timeit

timeit(setup='''
import random
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyz" * 100
num = 1000000
indexes = [random.choices(range(len(s)), k=2) for _ in range(num)]
def swap(s: str, index1: int, index2: int) -> str:
    new_s = list(s)
    new_s[index1], new_s[index2] = new_s[index2], new_s[index1]
    return "".join(new_s)
''',
stmt='for i in range(num): swap(s, *indexes[i])',
number=1
)
```

the string-based functions are about 15x faster than the list-based function.

**Update**

Prompted by a comment, I benchmarked the two methods of swapping the index values, calling the functions with 2 random numbers, swapping the order of the inputs for a second call to remove any bias for a particular ordering. The testing code was:

```
timeit(setup='''
import random
i1, i2 = random.choices(range(1000000), k=2)
def swap(index1: int, index2: int) -> (int, int):
    lindex = min(index1, index2)
    gindex = max(index1, index2)
    return lindex, gindex
''', stmt='''
swap(i1, i2)
swap(i2, i1)
''',
number=1000000
)

timeit(setup='''
import random
i1, i2 = random.choices(range(1000000), k=2)
def swap(index1: int, index2: int) -> (int, int):
    lindex, gindex = (index1, index2) if index1 < index2 else (index2, index1)
    return lindex, gindex
''', stmt='''
swap(i1, i2)
swap(i2, i1)
''',
number=1000000
)
```

On my computer, the results were:

```
min/max     0.4447700999735389
if/else     0.22195569999166764
```

So about 2x faster for the if test.

Comment: Did you time your way of getting `lindex, gindex` against `min, max`?  I'm curious how much of a difference it actually makes.

Comment: @MarkRansom I didn't test that directly; in my tests of the string swapping function the one using my way was about 10-30% faster than the other, but then I think the execution time is largely dependent on the string swap itself (the difference was more for shorter string lengths). I'll test the index thing on its own shortly and update.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've added benchmarking data for that. The `if/else` method is about 2x faster on my computer.